# IIS replying with cached results but console application does not

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have a service that is built on top of SQL Server. The service runs as a windows service.
I have created a dll file that I can use in my `ASP.net` project that talks to this service to get data.

If I use the dll file in a console application, I always get new results.
However if I use the dll in the `ASP.net' project, I get cached results of following function call.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetTreeData()
        {
            IRemediationService svc = new RemediationService();
            var tree = svc.GetTreeData();
            return Json(tree, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I thought client browser is caching the results, but I ran the application in debug mode, arrived at the `GetTreeData` function call and checked the results to see that it had old values so browser is not caching anything.

Here are the headers sent to IIS as found it in Google chrome for this request.

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:64387
Pragma:no-cache
```

The response headers are

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:111578
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 13 Sep 2013 15:18:59 GMT
Persistent-Auth:true
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

You might think the back end is caching the results however the console application always gets whatever is there on the back end SQL server.
Here is the code I use. If I run the console application in debug mode and see the results of this function call, its always the latest.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IRemediationService svc = new RemediationService();    
            var tree = svc.GetTreeData();   
         }
```

Please help so IIS will always query results instead of replying with whats in there in its memory cache.

Comment: What happens when you add a breakpoint inside the web application running on IIS? Does the code to call retrieve data from the service called?

Comment: The code `var tree= svc.GetTreeData()` executes and returns the old data in web application.

Comment: Can anyone please reply? I am getting cached results although the function call is executed.